# How to adjust Multicell in Array FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, billing, erp

i need a help on how to make the data inside the array to be in one ligne and same height in multicell

this is the result
[image]

and this is the code :

```
  $colored = false;
  foreach($products_info as $row){

      if($colored){
          $this->SetFillColor(218,218,218);              
      }else{
          $this->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
         
      }
    
    $this->Cell(40,15,ucwords($row["libelle"]),1,0,'L',$colored);
    
    $this->MultiCell(40,15,ucwords($row["description"]),1,1,'L',$colored);

    $this->Cell(40,15,number_format($row["prix_unitaire"],3,","," "),1,0,"C",$colored);
    $this->Cell(20,15,number_format($row["quantity"],3,","," "),1,0,"C",$colored);
    $this->Cell(10,15,number_format($row["largeur"],3,","," "),1,0,"C",$colored);
    $this->Cell(10,15,number_format($row["hauteur"],3,","," "),1,0,"C",$colored);
    $this->Cell(30,15,number_format($row["total_ht"],3,","," "),1,1,"R",$colored);
    $colored = !$colored;
  }
```

this is the old version before i add multicell
[image]

and this is the code :

```
      $colored = false;
  foreach($products_info as $row){

      if($colored){
          $this->SetFillColor(218,218,218);              
      }else{
          $this->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
         
      }
    
    $this->Cell(40,15,ucwords($row["libelle"]),1,0,'L',$colored);
    $this->Cell(40,15,ucwords($row["description"]),1,0,'L',$colored);
    $this->Cell(40,15,number_format($row["prix_unitaire"],3,","," "),1,0,"C",$colored);
    $this->Cell(20,15,number_format($row["quantity"],3,","," "),1,0,"C",$colored);
    $this->Cell(10,15,number_format($row["largeur"],3,","," "),1,0,"C",$colored);
    $this->Cell(10,15,number_format($row["hauteur"],3,","," "),1,0,"C",$colored);
    $this->Cell(30,15,number_format($row["total_ht"],3,","," "),1,1,"R",$colored);
    $colored = !$colored;
  }
```

Comment: `MultiCell()` has different arguments compared to `Cell()`.

Comment: i know , but my question is how to add 7 `multicell()` next to each other in one line @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Have you tried to use the correct arguments for `MultiCell()`? If so, what happens?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes, the result was one under the other

Comment: FPDF uses a X and Y position. The next cell will be printed there. If you want it somewhere else use `SetXY(float x, float y)` to change the position.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes that's it , i found a solution using `setX()` and `setY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution in github [enter link description here](https://github.com/gemul/fpdf-multicell-table)

[image]

i use these functions

```
function SetWidths($w)
{
    //Tableau des largeurs de colonnes
    $this->widths=$w;
}

function SetAligns($a)
{
    //Tableau des alignements de colonnes
    $this->aligns=$a;
}

function Row($data,$bool)
{
    //Calcule la hauteur de la ligne
    $nb=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
        $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
    $h=10*$nb;
    //Effectue un saut de page si nécessaire
    $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
    //Dessine les cellules

    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        $w=$this->widths[$i];
        $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ?  'C' : 'C';

        //Sauve la position courante
        $x=$this->GetX();
        $y=$this->GetY();
        //Dessine le cadre

        if($bool){
          $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h,'DF');             
        }
        else  
        {
          $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);
        }

          
        //Imprime le texte
        $this->MultiCell($w,10,$data[$i],0,$a);
        //Repositionne à droite
        $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);

      
        
    }
    //Va à la ligne
    $this->Ln($h);
}

function CheckPageBreak($h)
{
    //Si la hauteur h provoque un débordement, saut de page manuel
    if($this->GetY()+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger)
        $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation);
}

function NbLines($w,$txt)
{
    //Calcule le nombre de lignes qu'occupe un MultiCell de largeur w
    $cw=&$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    if($w==0)
        $w=$this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax=($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
    $s=str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    $nb=strlen($s);
    if($nb>0 && $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
        $nb--;
    $sep=-1;
    $i=0;
    $j=0;
    $l=0;
    $nl=1;
    while($i<$nb)
    {
        $c=$s[$i];
        if($c=="\n")
        {
            $i++;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
            continue;
        }
        if($c==' ')
            $sep=$i;
        $l+=$cw[$c];
        if($l>$wmax)
        {
            if($sep==-1)
            {
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
            }
            else
                $i=$sep+1;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
    return $nl;
}
```

and here is my code after some changes :

```
      //Table de 7 colonnes
  $this->SetWidths(array(40,40,40,20,10,10,30));


  $colored = false;
  
  foreach($products_info as $row){
    $this->Row(
      array(
        ucwords($row["libelle"]),
        ucwords($row["description"]),
        number_format($row["prix_unitaire"],3,","," "),
        number_format($row["quantity"],3,","," "),
        number_format($row["largeur"],3,","," "),
        number_format($row["hauteur"],3,","," "),
        number_format($row["total_ht"],3,","," ")
      ), $colored);

      $colored = !$colored ; 
  }
```